# Integer+Integer in java 1.4

Tags: java

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
Integer i2 = new Integer(20);
Integer i3 = i1+i2;
```

Why in Java 1.7 this code works fine, but in java 1.4 I have error:

```
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer
```

This is autoboxing issue or operator "+" is defined for Integer in java 1.7?

How to proceed Integer+Integer in java 1.4 then?

Comment: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html discusses what needs to be done for 1.4.

Comment: Dude you need to upgrade that .... JRE version.

Comment: Why don't just use int instead of Integer?

Answer (score 14):

Because autoboxing and unboxing is introduced from [java 5 onwards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Java 1.4 can't understand that syntax.

> How to proceed Integer+Integer

You need to get primitive `int` using [intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and then do addition on primitive values.

Comment: Autoboxing AND unboxing ;)

Answer (score 11):

Java 1.4 did not have autoboxing of `Integer` variables. That came along in Java 1.5.

See [What's New in Java 1.5: Autoboxing/Unboxing](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/jett/sstamm/#_boxing)

Prior to that you had to do things like:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
Integer i2 = new Integer(20);
Integer i3 = new Integer(i1.intValue() + i2.intValue());
```

Answer (score 3):

[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in 1.4 doesn't [autobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in 1.7 does.

You want something like:

```
int i3 = i1.intValue() + i2.intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing/Unboxing is done by javac. If we decompile .class we will see how exactly this is done:

```
    Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
    Integer i2 = new Integer(20);
    Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(i1.intValue() + i2.intValue());
```